# CAS Server Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cas

I am implementing CAS server without using maven, have configured properly here is my `deployerConfigContext.xml` configuration:

```
<!-- This is the EntityManagerFactory configuration for Hibernate -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>-->

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing"
    p:password="***" p:username="root" />
```

now when I am trying to start the CAS server, it is throwing following exception:-

`2014-02-12 18:49:06,664 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Context initialization failed>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servicesManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'serviceRegistryDao' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/ObjectPool`

Please help;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `commons-pool-x.jar` dependency is missing...

Comment: Thanks jleleu, have added and now it works fine but now I am getting different exception says: `No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}`

Comment: You should find it here: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/3.5.x/cas-server-webapp/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml